# i can't iterate column names dynamically in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

i want to get object values from database. At the same time i want that my column names be dynamic. i got column names from model and i got one object from database. Then i sent them to my blade, In my blade i can't specify dynamic column name for object

my controller

```
public function index()
{//config('app.attributlar')
    //dd(gettype($sutunler));
      
    $about=About::first();
    $table=$about->getTable();
    $columns  = \Schema::getColumnListing($table);
    
    return view('admin.about.index')->with([
        'about'=>$about,
        'columns'=>$columns
    ]);
}
```

in my blade

```
@foreach($columns as $column)
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $about->{$column} }}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Why can't yo do that? What exactly is going wrong with the given code?

Comment: i want to iterate my column names dynamically in blade

Comment: @Shamuhammet did my answer not work?

Comment: @Shamuhammet and what's the problem about this? What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , it is similar to your approach: `$columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($table)`

Make sure that $table is your tables name. Otherwise this wont work.